# Не работает анимация в сафари и IE

Tags: css

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("button, [type=submit]");
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
links[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Remove any old one
    var ripple = document.querySelector('.ripple');
    if (ripple) {
        ripple.remove();
    }

    // Setup
    var buttonWidth = this.offsetWidth,
        buttonHeight = this.offsetHeight;

    // Make it round!
    if(buttonWidth >= buttonHeight) {
        buttonHeight = buttonWidth;
    } else {
        buttonWidth = buttonHeight;
    }

    // Get the center of the element
    var x = event.offsetX==undefined?event.layerX:event.offsetX - buttonWidth / 2,
        y = event.offsetY==undefined?event.layerY:event.offsetY - buttonHeight / 2;  //эфект волны при клике на кнопку

    // Add the element
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.className = 'ripple';
    s = span.style;
    s.width = buttonWidth + 'px';
    s.height = buttonHeight + 'px';
    s.top = y + 'px';
    s.left = x + 'px';
    this.appendChild(span);
});
}
```

```css
.ripple {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    -webkit-transform:  scale(0);
    -moz-transform:  scale(0);
    -ms-transform:  scale(0);
    -o-transform:  scale(0);
    transform:  scale(0);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: ripple 0.5s linear;
    -o-animation: ripple 0.5s linear;
    animation: ripple 0.5s linear;
}
@keyframes ripple {
  100% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(2);
      -moz-transform: scale(2);
      -ms-transform: scale(2);
      -o-transform: scale(2);
      transform: scale(2);
   opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Почему нету анимации клика в сафари а IE как исправить?

Comment: Я и в Firefox не вижу никакой анимации

Comment: А полностью менять вопрос на другой с помощью правки нехорошо

Comment: [Animation](https://caniuse.com/#search=animation) и [transform](https://caniuse.com/#search=transform) можно использовать в ИЕ11 и Сафари 10.3, 11.2, 11.3. В других версиях не поддерживаются. Вам для каких версий оно нужно?

Comment: **Статус: проблема не воспроизводится у меня**. BrowserStack, macOS High Sierra, Safari 11.1 — анимация [**работает как в Firefox**](https://i.imgur.com/nIS4mFw.gif). Vlad467, как Вы определили, что Ваш код не работает в Safari? Какую версию Safari используете? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В IE не работает метод `remove` но есть полифилл https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

```js
(function() {
  var arr = [window.Element, window.CharacterData, window.DocumentType];
  var args = [];

  arr.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item) {
      args.push(item.prototype);
    }
  });

  // from:https://github.com/jserz/js_piece/blob/master/DOM/ChildNode/remove()/remove().md
  (function (arr) {
    arr.forEach(function (item) {
      if (item.hasOwnProperty('remove')) {
        return;
      }
      Object.defineProperty(item, 'remove', {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: function remove() {
          this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        }
      });
    });
  })(args);
})();

var links = document.querySelectorAll("button, [type=submit]");
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
links[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Remove any old one
    var ripple = document.querySelector('.ripple');
    if (ripple) {
        ripple.remove();
    }

    // Setup
    var buttonWidth = this.offsetWidth,
        buttonHeight = this.offsetHeight;

    // Make it round!
    if(buttonWidth >= buttonHeight) {
        buttonHeight = buttonWidth;
    } else {
        buttonWidth = buttonHeight;
    }

    // Get the center of the element
    var x = event.offsetX==undefined?event.layerX:event.offsetX - buttonWidth / 2,
        y = event.offsetY==undefined?event.layerY:event.offsetY - buttonHeight / 2;  //эфект волны при клике на кнопку

    // Add the element
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.className = 'ripple';
    s = span.style;
    s.width = buttonWidth + 'px';
    s.height = buttonHeight + 'px';
    s.top = y + 'px';
    s.left = x + 'px';
    this.appendChild(span);
});
}
```

```css
.ripple {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    -webkit-transform:  scale(0);
    -moz-transform:  scale(0);
    -ms-transform:  scale(0);
    -o-transform:  scale(0);
    transform:  scale(0);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: ripple 0.5s linear;
    -o-animation: ripple 0.5s linear;
    animation: ripple 0.5s linear;
}
@keyframes ripple {
  100% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(2);
      -moz-transform: scale(2);
      -ms-transform: scale(2);
      -o-transform: scale(2);
      transform: scale(2);
   opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="background:blue; border:1px solid #ccc;">Click</button>
```

Comment: а с сафари что делать?

Comment: @Vlad467, открыть консоль и почитать где ошибка

Comment: @Vlad467 с сафари не знаю т.к. у меня нет mac os

Answer (score 0):

Может поможет код с этой темы

http://fian.my.id/Waves/#examples

Browser support

IE 10++

Chrome 14++

Firefox 9++

Safari 5.1++

Opera 11.6++

iOS 6++ (Safari)

Windows Phone 8.1 (IE)

Android Browser 4++